# self-defined function raising unexpected TypeError

Tags: python, function, matplotlib, typeerror

I defined a function to perform plotting, which is shown as follows. The code runs without a problem when i directly use the commands and do not call a function.

```
def plot_2D(wv, colors = None):
    plt.style.use('ggplot')

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.scatter(wv.T[0], wv.T[1], c = colors)# s=sizes,vmin=-50, vmax=50 
    ax.set(xlim=(-5, 5), xticks=np.arange(-5, 5),
        ylim=(-5, 5), yticks=np.arange(-5, 5))
    plt.show()
```

However, when I called the function as follows

```
plot_2D(wv_pca, colors = categories)
```

There is unexpected error: `TypeError: plot_2D() got an unexpected keyword argument 'colors'`. It is quite confusing! Is it about parameter passing?

I don't know what's wrong, and how to fix it. SOS!

Comment: There's something missing from this - this error would not be reproducible from the code you've given. There is another `plot_2D` function in your scope from somewhere

Comment: If you haven't re-defined the function, then the next culprit would be `from some_package import *`

Comment: Yep, i defined the function in another file, and used `from utils.visual import *` to import. Now it's showing a `ImportError: cannot import name 'plot_2D_c' from 'utils.visual'`